# I am getting module 'boto3 ' has no attribute 'client' error when running the python script using sudo

Tags: python-3.x, linux, boto3

When I run the python script like this `python3 server.py` it works, however when I run it like `sudo python3 server.py` I get an error of module 'boto3 ' has no attribute 'client'

Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have likely installed the boto3 library in user mode (`pip install boto3 --user`). Simply `sudo pip install boto3` to fix this. Understand that there are some pitfalls to this method, since the sudo-installed version of boto3 will become the system-wide version. If you are not using virtual environments, this is a perfect use case to start using them.

- [Python Docs for VENV](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)
- [RealPython Primer](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)